# Not saving user data to users table in laravel 5.6

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am going to insert new data records to users table in laravel 5.6. this is My UserController,

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
         'name' => 'required|max:255',
         'userlevel' => 'required',
         'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
]);
$user = new User();
        $user->name = $request->input('name');
        $user->uservalue = $request->input('uservalue');
        $user->email = $request->input('email');
        $user->password = $request->input(bcrypt($data['password']));
        $user->save();
        return redirect()->route('users.show', $user->id);
    }
```

and blade file is,

```
<form action="{{route('users.store')}}" method="POST">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name">Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Enter Name">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
            <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1">User Level</label>
            <select class="form-control" id="uservalue" name="uservalue">
            <option>0</option>
            <option>2</option>
            <option>1</option>

            </select>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" name="email" placeholder="Enter Email">
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="password" name="password" placeholder="Enter Password">

            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Create User</button>
        </form>
        </div>
```

route is,

```
Route::resource('/users','UserController');
```

But when I clicked submit button data not saving to users table. not any error message occurred. only refresh page. how can fixed this problem?

Comment: Looks Like validation is falied in controller. But your View did not have section to show validation message. You validated userlevel in your controller. But there is no input named userlevel. Check this first

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
public function store(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validate($request,[
         'name' => 'required|max:255',
         'uservalue' => 'required',
         'email' => 'required|email|unique:users',
]);
$user = new User();
        $user->name = $request->input('name');
        $user->uservalue = $request->input('uservalue');
        $user->email = $request->input('email');
        $user->password = $request->input(bcrypt($data['password']));
        $user->save();
        return redirect()->route('users.show', $user->id);
    }
```

please Change userlevel to uservalue

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem is here `$request->input(bcrypt($data['password']))` You are passing $data but not defining it. simply try this: `bcrypt($request->input('password'))`

Also, you are validating `userlevel` but inserting `uservalue`.